# errors when trying to compile java project from github (windows)

Tags: java, maven, github, compiler-errors

i don't understand anything in java but i need to compile this project

Github project:

https://github.com/MitchTalmadge/Emoji-Tools

i have installed jdk and maven

then typed this in Powershell

and i got this :)

`mvn compile`

```
    PS C:\Users\nulla\Desktop\Emoji-Tools-master> mvn compile
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [WARNING]
    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mitchtalmadge:Emoji-Tools:jar:1.9
    [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 13, column 21
    [WARNING]
    [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
    [WARNING]
    [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
    [WARNING]
    [INFO]
    [INFO] -------------------< com.mitchtalmadge:Emoji-Tools >--------------------
    [INFO] Building Emoji-Tools 1.9
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [WARNING] The POM for com.jcraft:jzlib:jar:1.1.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
    [WARNING] The POM for org.python:jython-standalone:jar:2.7.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
    [WARNING] The POM for commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
    [WARNING] The POM for org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:jar:4.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
    [WARNING] The POM for commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
    [WARNING] The POM for junit:junit:jar:4.12 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Emoji-Tools ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Copying 195 resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Emoji-Tools ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Compiling 53 source files to C:\Users\nulla\Desktop\Emoji-Tools-master\target\classes
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\com\jcraft\jzlib\1.1.3\jzlib-1.1.3.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\org\python\jython-standalone\2.7.0\jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\org\imgscalr\imgscalr-lib\4.2\imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/conversion/converter/PNGFilterHandler.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.conversion.converter
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/dialogs/dialogcontrollers/ErrorReportDialogController.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.dialogs.dialogcontrollers
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/renaming/RenamingWorker.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.renaming
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ConverterTabController.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/conversion/ConversionInfo.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.conversion
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/deletion/DeletionOperation.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.deletion
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/FontType.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/packaging/PackagingOperation.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.packaging
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/extraction/extractors/GoogleExtractionWorker.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.extraction.extractors
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/MainController.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/splitting/splitters/AppleSplitterWorker.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.splitting.splitters
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/extraction/Ligature.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.extraction
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/JythonHandler.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/packaging/packagingthreads/GooglePackagingWorker.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.packaging.packagingthreads
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/resizing/ResizingInfo.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.resizing
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/dialogs/OperationFinishedDialog.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.dialogs
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/splitting/SplittingOperation.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.splitting
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[34,8] cannot access java.lang
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[39,17] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[39,48] cannot find symbol
      symbol: class Initializable
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[37,13] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class ToggleGroup
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[40,13] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class RadioButton
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[43,13] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class RadioButton
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[46,13] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class ToggleGroup
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[49,13] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class RadioButton
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[52,13] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class RadioButton
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[55,13] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class LimitingTextField
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[76,15] cannot access FileChooser
      zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[81,44] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class File
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[42,5] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class Label
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[45,5] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class TextField
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[48,5] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class Button
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[51,5] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class Button
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[54,5] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class Button
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[56,5] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class Operation
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[58,5] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class File
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[61,28] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class URL
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[61,42] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class ResourceBundle
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[68,30] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class ActionEvent
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[95,35] package FileChooser does not exist
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[97,53] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class File
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[100,41] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class ActionEvent
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[110,29] cannot find symbol
      symbol:   class ActionEvent
      location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [INFO] 48 errors
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  9.310 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-12T18:05:54+03:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Emoji-Tools: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\com\jcraft\jzlib\1.1.3\jzlib-1.1.3.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\org\python\jython-standalone\2.7.0\jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\org\imgscalr\imgscalr-lib\4.2\imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\nulla\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar; zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/conversion/converter/PNGFilterHandler.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.conversion.converter
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/dialogs/dialogcontrollers/ErrorReportDialogController.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.dialogs.dialogcontrollers
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/renaming/RenamingWorker.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.renaming
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ConverterTabController.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/conversion/ConversionInfo.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.conversion
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/deletion/DeletionOperation.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.deletion
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/FontType.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/packaging/PackagingOperation.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.packaging
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/extraction/extractors/GoogleExtractionWorker.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.extraction.extractors
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/MainController.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/splitting/splitters/AppleSplitterWorker.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.splitting.splitters
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/extraction/Ligature.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.extraction
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/JythonHandler.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/packaging/packagingthreads/GooglePackagingWorker.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.packaging.packagingthreads
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/resizing/ResizingInfo.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.resizing
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/dialogs/OperationFinishedDialog.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.dialogs
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/operations/splitting/SplittingOperation.java:[19,1] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.operations.splitting
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[34,8] cannot access java.lang
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[39,17] cannot access com.mitchtalmadge
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[39,48] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol: class Initializable
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[37,13] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class ToggleGroup
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[40,13] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class RadioButton
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[43,13] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class RadioButton
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[46,13] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class ToggleGroup
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[49,13] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class RadioButton
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[52,13] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class RadioButton
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[55,13] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class LimitingTextField
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[76,15] cannot access FileChooser
    [ERROR]   zip END header not found
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/ExtractorTabController.java:[81,44] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class File
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.ExtractorTabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[42,5] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[45,5] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class TextField
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[48,5] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Button
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[51,5] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Button
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[54,5] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Button
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[56,5] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Operation
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[58,5] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class File
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[61,28] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class URL
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[61,42] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class ResourceBundle
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[68,30] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class ActionEvent
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[95,35] package FileChooser does not exist
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[97,53] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class File
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[100,41] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class ActionEvent
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/nulla/Desktop/Emoji-Tools-master/src/main/java/com/mitchtalmadge/emojitools/gui/tabcontrollers/TabController.java:[110,29] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class ActionEvent
    [ERROR]   location: class com.mitchtalmadge.emojitools.gui.tabcontrollers.TabController
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Seems the maven artifacts are corrupted. Delete them and try again.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose and what are these?

Answer (score 0):

Odds are that your maven artifacts are corrupted (as @Seelenvirtuose) mentioned.

To delete all maven artifacts, go in

```
C:\Users\your_user_tag\.m2\repository\Maven
```

and delete everything. Then run (same place you ran your first mvn compile)

```
mvn compile
```

This will cause maven to detect that there are no artifacts, hence maven will redownload all artifacts from scratch.

Comment: thanks, but this path doesn't exist,  

i tried to compile it using linux wsl (on windows),  

`apt-get install java`,  

`apt-get install maven`,  

also i checked `mvn -v` and `java -version`, 

everything was looking great, 

but then i get the same error :), 

would you please just compile it for me,

Comment: Do you only need the jar file or the exe file ? Because if you do, they are already available in https://github.com/MitchTalmadge/Emoji-Tools/releases

Comment: i knew some one is going to say that but i want to compile it myself